# Automatically inserting braces in the correct position in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I used eclipse for more than a year now and I am currently trying NetBeans to see the differences. One feature that seems to be missing from NetBeans is the option to automatically place curly braces in the correct position. For example, in eclipse you can type your curly brace inside the parantheses and it will automatically appear in the correct position.

```
public static void main (String[] args /* In eclipse you can type your curly brace here*/) {
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: NetBeans is even better, just type: `psvm` then hit tab.

Comment: @MrLore In Eclipse you can also type `main` and hit `Ctrl-Space` and the same thing will happen. I guess the example given was an unfortunate one.

Comment: So... what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro for this and assign it to Ctrl+{ or the shortcut of your choosing.

Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Macros

caret-end-line " {" insert-break